# DRF: HTTP 401 logged at ERROR level. How to lower logging level?

Tags: python, django, logging, django-rest-framework

I am trying to enable email alerts when HTTP 500 errors happens. Everything works fine, except that a `Authentication credentials were not provided` (HTTP 401) error is logged at `ERROR` level, which is way too verbose for email alerts.

Here is the email content (Django settings omitted here):

> Report at /
>
> [35mb'{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}' [0m
>
> Request Method:   GET
>
> Request
>   URL:  https://myapi.org/dev/
>
> Django Version:   2.0.2
>
> Python Executable:    /var/lang/bin/python3.6
>
> Python Version:   3.6.1

Also, I am using the `django-request-logging` module to print requests' content.

Here is my logging config:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'email_backend': 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend',
            'include_html': True,
            'filters': [],
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'mail_admins'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}
```

Any idea how I could filter out HTTP 401 from the `mail_admins` handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/Rhumbix/django-request-logging) for `django-request-logger`:

> If HTTP status code is between 400 - 599, URIs are logged at ERROR level, otherwise they are logged at INFO level.
>
> See `REQUEST_LOGGING_HTTP_4XX_LOG_LEVEL` setting to override this.

And the documentation for that setting explains how to change the log level:

> By default, HTTP status codes between 400 - 499 are logged at `ERROR` level. You can set `REQUEST_LOGGING_HTTP_4XX_LOG_LEVEL = logging.WARNING` (etc) to override this.

Comment: After testing, it does not seem to affect the logging level of 401 errors. Could it be a default Django error?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure it is this app. Maybe you are not using the latest version?

Comment: Exactly! It turns out their latest release on PyPi is old and does not contain the change for the log level! Problem solved!